# NameError: name 'Usuario' is not defined

Tags: python, django, migration, models

I have this error in django when i try to do "makemigrations"

Code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    amigos = models.ManyToManyField(Amigo)



class Amigo(models.Model):  
    usuarios = models.ForeignKey(Usuario)



class Regalo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    enlace_compra = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amigo_encargado = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Sorry, my english is very poor and I use translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Amigo` class did not defined on moment of declaration of `Usuario` class, so you cant use it in amigos field.

From django docs:

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been
>   defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model
>   object itself

change this line in `Usuario` class:

```
amigos = models.ManyToManyField(Amigo)
```

to:

```
amigos = models.ManyToManyField('Amigo')
```

Comment: @jandresplp no, without quotes you cant use this model (Usuario)